# Confused about the node when making linked lists

Tags: python, linked-list

I'm trying to make a linked list in python without using classes. But I'm a little confused.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:
head = [None,None]
n = integer
and the function is getting called from a loop

```
def append(head, n):
    node = head
    while node[1] != None: # Find last node
        node = node[1]
    node[1] = [n,None]  # Attach new node
```

Basically using a node that holds a value and points to next. Now I'm trying to do something similar with my program, the main difference being that the example gets the head which contains [None,None] and in my program I get 10 empty lists instead. This is what I got:

```
def add(word_set,word):
    node = word_set
    node[-1] = [word,None]
    while node[1] != None:
        node = node[1]
        node[1] = [word,None]
```

getting called by this from main:

```
names = ["Ella", "Owen", "Fred", "Zoe", "Adam", "Ceve", "Adam", "Ceve", "Jonas", "Ola", "Morgan", "Fredrik", "Simon", "Albin", "Måns", "Amer", "David"]

word_set = ws.new_empty_set()
for s in names:
    ws.add(word_set,s)
```

I dont quite know how to replicate the example function with my code. I always get index out of range when I try. Also I dont want to make any changes to main.py

Comment: If `word_set` is an empty sequence, `node[-1]` will be out of bounds since `node` will be empty. You could pass in a list of `[None, None]` or something instead? Or just `node = [word,None]`.

Comment: I assume that the last line of your `add` function is indented one position too far and should not be part of the `while`.  If that's true, then the only substantive difference between these two functions is the line `node[-1] = [word,None]`.  But if nodes always have 2 elements, which it seems they do in your version too, then that's the same as  `node[1] = [word,None]`. What that kubw seems to be doing then is cutting off the list that `word_set` was pointing to, guaranteeing that your list will always have its first node plus two nodes following both containing the same word.

Comment: @Steve `ws` appears to be a module name, not an object. So `ws.add(word_set, s)` presumably adds `s` to `word_set`.

Comment: The line `node[1] = [word,None]` should not be inside the `while` loop. It needs to be after the loop, just like in the `append()` function.

Comment: Oh yes.  Didn't think code this simple would be broken into modules, but that makes perfect sense (no classes, right?).  I agree with you on that one line being too indented...I said the same thing above.

Answer (score 0):

Some issues:

- Assuming that `new_empty_set` returns an empty list, in `add` the assignment `node[-1] =`  will produce the error that you mention. You should verify first whether the list is empty and deal with that boundary case separately.
- The last line of `add` should not be part of the loop. It should be executed after the loop finishes.
- Less important, but using the name "set" is confusing, as `set` is a native type that is not a list, but a hash set. So I would use the term "linked_list" instead

Corrected code:

```
# assuming this definition, but don't call it *set
#   but *linked_list:
def new_empty_linked_list():
    return []

def add(word_linked_list, word):   # change of name
    node = word_linked_list
    if not node:  # the list is empty
        node.extend([word, None])
    else:
        while node[1] != None:
            node = node[1]
        node[1] = [word, None]  # outside of loop

names = ["Ella", "Owen", "Fred", "Zoe", "Adam", "Ceve", "Adam", "Ceve", "Jonas", "Ola", "Morgan", "Fredrik", "Simon", "Albin", "Måns", "Amer", "David"]

word_linked_list = new_empty_linked_list()
for s in names:
    add(word_linked_list, s)

print(word_linked_list)
```

There are some duplicate names in your input. You haven't mentioned what should happen with those, and your `add` function doesn't deal with them differently. But if the list should not store duplicates, then you should add some condition in your loop:

```
def add(word_linked_list, word):
    node = word_linked_list
    if not node:
        node.extend([word, None])
    else:
        # add condition to spot duplicate value
        while node[0] != word and node[1] != None:
            node = node[1]
        if node[0] != word:  # only add when unique
            node[1] = [word, None]
```

Comment: I tried your code and unfortunately it still gives me list index out of range.

Comment: It runs fine [on repl.it](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcomq645463735459839). There must be other code responsible for that error.